# Getting Error on Rebuilding Link Databases - Master Database

Tags: sitecore-commerce

I am getting the below error while Rebuild Link Databases.

Sitecore Version: Sitecore.NET 9.0.2 (rev. 180604).

attached screen shots.

Other Databases are rebuilding successfully, only master is throwing the below exception.

Please let me know if you need any more information from my side.

```
Job started: RebuildLinkDatabasesIndex|System.ArgumentNullException: Value cannot be null.
Parameter name: value
   at Newtonsoft.Json.Linq.Extensions.Value[T,U](IEnumerable`1 value)
   at Sitecore.Commerce.Engine.Connect.DataProvider.ReadOnlyCatalogDataProvider.<>c.<GetItemVersions>b__7_0(JToken x)
   at System.Linq.Enumerable.FirstOrDefault[TSource](IEnumerable`1 source, Func`2 predicate)
   at Sitecore.Commerce.Engine.Connect.DataProvider.ReadOnlyCatalogDataProvider.GetItemVersions(ItemDefinition item, CallContext context)
   at Sitecore.Data.DataProviders.DataProvider.GetItemVersions(ItemDefinition item, CallContext context, DataProviderCollection providers)
   at Sitecore.Data.DataSource.LoadVersions(ItemDefinition definition, Language language)
   at Sitecore.Data.DataSource.GetVersions(ItemInformation itemInformation, Language language)
   at Sitecore.Data.DataSource.GetLatestVersion(ItemInformation itemInformation, Language language)
   at Sitecore.Data.DataSource.GetItemData(ID itemID, Language language, Version version)
   at Sitecore.Nexus.Data.DataCommands.GetItemCommand.GetItem(ID , Language , Version , Database )
   at Sitecore.Nexus.Data.DataCommands.GetItemCommand.Execute(ID , Language , Version , Database )
   at Sitecore.Data.Engines.DataCommands.GetItemCommand.DoExecute()
   at Sitecore.Data.Engines.EngineCommand`2.Execute()
   at Sitecore.Data.Managers.ItemProvider.GetItem(ID itemId, Language language, Version version, Database database)
   at Sitecore.Data.Managers.ItemProvider.GetItem(ID itemId, Language language, Version version, Database database, SecurityCheck securityCheck)
   at Sitecore.ContentTesting.Pipelines.ItemProvider.GetItem.GetItemUnderTestProcessor.Process(GetItemArgs args)
   at (Object , Object )
   at Sitecore.Pipelines.CorePipeline.Run(PipelineArgs args)
   at Sitecore.Data.Managers.DefaultItemManager.GetItem(ID itemId, Language language, Version version, Database database, SecurityCheck securityCheck)
   at Sitecore.Data.Managers.ItemManager.GetItem(ID itemId, Language language, Version version, Database database, SecurityCheck securityCheck)
   at Sitecore.Nexus.Data.DataCommands.GetChildrenCommand.Execute(Item  )
   at Sitecore.Data.Engines.EngineCommand`2.Execute()
   at Sitecore.Data.Managers.ItemProvider.GetChildren(Item item, ChildListOptions options)
   at Sitecore.Data.Managers.ItemProvider.GetChildren(Item item, SecurityCheck securityCheck, ChildListOptions options)
   at Sitecore.Data.Items.Item.GetChildren(ChildListOptions options)
   at Sitecore.Links.LinkDatabase.RebuildItem(Item item)
   at Sitecore.Links.LinkDatabase.RebuildItem(Item item)
   at Sitecore.Links.LinkDatabase.RebuildItem(Item item)
   at Sitecore.Links.LinkDatabase.RebuildItem(Item item)
   at Sitecore.Links.LinkDatabase.RebuildItem(Item item)
   at Sitecore.Links.LinkDatabase.RebuildItem(Item item)
   at Sitecore.Links.LinkDatabase.RebuildItem(Item item)
   at Sitecore.Links.LinkDatabase.RebuildItem(Item item)
   at Sitecore.Links.LinkDatabase.RebuildItem(Item item)
   at Sitecore.Links.LinkDatabase.RebuildItem(Item item)
   at Sitecore.Links.LinkDatabase.RebuildItem(Item item)
   at Sitecore.Links.LinkDatabase.RebuildItem(Item item)
   at Sitecore.Links.LinkDatabase.Rebuild(Database database)
   at Sitecore.Shell.Applications.Dialogs.RebuildLinkDatabase.RebuildLinkDatabaseForm.Builder.Build()|Job ended: RebuildLinkDatabasesIndex (units processed: )
```

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: Seems like its trying to connect with commerce engine but not able to get the catalog data, is your commerce engine service configured well, and that is up and running?

Comment: Hi Vipin, thank you, yes i am able to connect to Business Tools from sitecore, i have added the screenshots to my post. i have same thumbprint in CommerceAuthoring_Sc9, mysite.xconnect. please let me know what else i can check and where.

Comment: The thumbprint should be same in commerce engine roles and Sitecore.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is with the catalog items. You can exclude the catalog in CMS by unchecking the checkbox and then try to rebuild. If this works then you can further debug to find out which product is throwing this exception